# RegEx: matching a <tag> with random order attributes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match an `<a>` tag, containing an id and href in an unknown order.

The current regex I have right now is

```
/<[Aa]\s[^>]*(href="http:\/\/example.com"|id="badge")\s[^>]*(href="http:\/\/example.com"|id="badge")[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/';
```

The code I'm matching on is

```
<a id="badge" target="_blank" href="http://example.com">
  <img src="">
</a>
```

Is there a more efficient way to match for the `<a>` tag?

Comment: The question specifically asks about efficiency. If you're looking for processing speed, then regex is the faster solution. If you're looking for ease of use, maintainability and robustness, then an HTML parser is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to match for the `<a>` tag would be to not use regex at all. You don't say which platform you are using, but I'll wager it has a decent HTML parser that you could leverage.